# Insert a formula into a specific cell using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

After searching for some examples I couldn't get it to work properly and I can't seem to find the error.

Here is the formula wich works properly (french functions) and I want to execute a macro to load this formula in the cell A2.

```
Range("A2").Formula = "=STXT(A1;CHERCHE(""["";A1)+1;CHERCHE("" "";A1;CHERCHE(""["";A1))-CHERCHE(""["";A1)-1)"
```

Comment: Either use `.FormulaLocal` or change the formula into the US-EN version.

Comment: When you write a formula in VBA, you need to specify the code in English - or use `FormulaLocal` (but that's a terrible idea because your code should be language independent).